# php expand string from file_get_contents

Tags: string, expand

i have a file with below data

> this is a text file with html format $testarray['G']

i use this script but it is not work properly.

```
<?php $testarray=array();
$testarray['G']=100;
$result222 =file_get_contents(realpath('file.php'));
printf($result222);?>
```

i want this script, print out below line

```
this is a text file with html format 100
```

i do't want to use include or require function because user can insert php code in this file and i do't want user can use php codes in this file

can anybody help me?
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you know the string you expect to perform a substitution on, you can always do it manually with [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). However, it looks like you want to be able to substitute arbitrary variables into the string, which I **implore** you to not do. You are giving this PHP script way too much power as is. I can think of a few exploits off the top of my head, such as injecting superglobals among simply brute forcing variable names.

**Edit:** I realize now that I also didn't give you the straightforward answer which does as you request: the [eval(](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)) function. You should be able to craft a string that assigns the contents of the file to a variable, which should perform variable substitutions by the PHP parser. Please don't use it, but if you do be very careful.

Comment: i don't know the string i expect to perform a substitution on.

Answer (score 0):

i used below script

```
$result222 =file_get_contents(realpath('file.php'));
$result222=str_replace(array("<?","?>"),"  ",$result222);
print eval("return<<<ENDEVAL\n$result222\nENDEVAL;\n");
```